# Plotting a GAM (error in the plot output)

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam

I have set up a GAM but when i plot it i run into the issue as below, does anyone know how to fix this issue? Data, model and plot code used below;

data snipet:

```
co2 month year timeStep
1   315.42     1 1959        1
2   316.31     2 1959        2
3   316.50     3 1959        3
4   317.56     4 1959        4
5   318.13     5 1959        5
6   318.00     6 1959        6
7   316.39     7 1959        7
8   314.65     8 1959        8
9   313.68     9 1959        9
10  313.18    10 1959       10
11  314.66    11 1959       11
12  315.43    12 1959       12
13  316.27     1 1960       13
14  316.81     2 1960       14
15  317.42     3 1960       15
16  318.87     4 1960       16
17  319.87     5 1960       17
18  319.43     6 1960       18
19  318.01     7 1960       19
20  315.74     8 1960       20
```

model and plot:

```
carbonD_model = gam(co2 ~ s(timeStep, k = 4, bs = "cs"),
                    data = carbonD,
                    family = gaussian(link = "identity"))

#predictions
preds = predict(carbonD_model, type = 'terms', se.fit = TRUE)

#plotting the model
ggplot(carbonD, aes(timeStep, co2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(timeStep, preds$fit), col = 'red')
```

currently plot this which is incorrect;

[image]

Update of new error;

[image]

Comment: `When type="terms" each component of the linear predictor is returned seperately (possibly with standard errors): this includes parametric model components, followed by each smooth component, but excludes any offset and any intercept.` I think you would want `type="response"`. check: `?predict.gam`

Comment: Yeh i get what your saying, although type="terms" makes sense here as i need to plot the estimates of the smooth function

Comment: `"terms"` is going to give you the estimates separated out. For example, if you had two smooth terms then `preds$fit` would be a `data.frame` with two columns. I believe you want to compare your actuals and fitted. `"response"` just means the all-in prediction on the scale of the response variable. You very likely want the intercept included in this prediction, which `"response"` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the built-in `co2` and `mgcv` library:

```r
library(data.table)
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)

carbonD <- data.table(co2 = as.vector(co2), time = as.vector(time(co2)))
carbonD[, year := trunc(time)]
carbonD[, month := (time - year) * 12 + 1]
carbonD[, timeStep := .I]

carbonD_model = gam(co2 ~ s(timeStep, k = 4, bs = "cs"),
                    data = carbonD,
                    family = gaussian(link = "identity"))

#predictions
preds = predict(carbonD_model, type = 'response', se.fit = TRUE)

#plotting the model
ggplot(carbonD, aes(timeStep, co2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(timeStep, preds$fit), col = 'red')
```

[image]

Now if you tried to add another term, your code would error out with:

```r
carbonD_model = gam(co2 ~ s(timeStep, k = 4, bs = "cs") + s(year, k = 3, bs = "cs"),
                    data = carbonD,
                    family = gaussian(link = "identity"))

#predictions
preds = predict(carbonD_model, type = 'terms', se.fit = TRUE)

#plotting the model
ggplot(carbonD, aes(timeStep, co2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(timeStep, preds$fit), col = 'red')

# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (468): y

# but changing it to response
preds = predict(carbonD_model, type = 'response', se.fit = TRUE)

#plotting the model
ggplot(carbonD, aes(timeStep, co2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(timeStep, preds$fit), col = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. How would i get it to work using type=terms (think this is what i need here, i have just set the predictions up incorrectly for it). Guess i need to put my smooth terms into a df before plotting?

Comment: @Joe The "fitted" value when using `type = "terms"` is achieved (in this case) by adding on the constant term, which is returned as an attribute of `preds` or simply via `coef(carbonD_model)[1]`. Hence what you want would be `preds$fit + coef(carbonD_model)[1]`. FYI: I wouldn't trust the standard errors of this model; as the residuals are clearly not independent.

Comment: Been trying this thisafternoon but dont seem to be able to get the plot right. Would you mind correcting me or pointing out where ive gone wrong here please? The code i have used is; ggplot(carbonD, aes(timeStep, co2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(preds$fit + coef(carbonD_model[1]), col = 'red')) I have updated what plot it produces in the question is that helps

Comment: It's not clear why you are wanting to use terms, because (especially as the model gets more complicated) it gets to be kind of nasty syntax, but it can work. Following @GavinSimpson's suggestion:
`fit <- preds$fit + coef(carbonD_model)[1]`

`#plotting the model
ggplot(carbonD, aes(timeStep, co2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(timeStep, fit), col = 'red')`
In your code your parentheses were messed up here: `coef(carbonD_model[1])` and you also had `col` in `aes`. It seems you can't use that syntax in `aes` anyways.

Comment: Yeh I understand what you're saying now i've seen it. Makes more sense to use response. Thanks both.